# Can't commit to cloned repository

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to commit to a local repository that was cloned from GitHub. I get the following error message

```
fatal: update_ref for ref 'HEAD': cannot lock ref 'HEAD': ref
refs/heads/master is at 2b459....[LOTS OF NUMBERS AND CHARACTERS]... 
but expected 000000000000000000000000000
```

The structure of the .git folder looks as follows:

[image]

output from `git status`:

```
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   src/actions/types.js
    new file:   src/components/auth/require_auth.js
    new file:   src/components/auth/signin.js
    new file:   src/components/auth/signout.js
    new file:   src/components/auth/signup.js
    new file:   src/components/feature.js
    new file:   src/components/header.js
    new file:   src/components/welcome.js
    new file:   src/reducers/auth_reducer.js
    new file:   style/react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css
```

out put from `git log --all --oneline --decorate --graph`:

```
* 1d2e02d (HEAD) First working version
* 2b459d6 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Create .babelrc
*   a7b92d5 Merge branch 'master' of github.com:StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter
|\  
| *   29ebda4 Merge pull request #8 from megadix/master
| |\  
| | * 7a74747 Filter out IntelliJ IDEA project files in .gitignore
| * |   decca90 Merge pull request #10 from dkarter/master
| |\ \  
| | * | 94692d5 Use destructuring to import Component
| | |/  
| * |   ff4d48c Merge pull request #24 from tsurupin/add-global-navigator
| |\ \  
| | * | d976e01 Add global navigator setting to modify the error, 'navigator is not defined', in testing with react-router link
| * | |   b198de2 Merge pull request #29 from hex13/master
| |\ \ \  
| | |/ /  
| |/| |   
| | * | 6246c47 fix typo in README.md
| |/ /  
* | | c62b60e moved babel config to webpack
|/ /  
* | 2eba18e (tag: 1.1.0) added reactrouter
* | 3ea279e Update package.json
* | 78c0fed tweak mocha test command for windows users
|/  
* 3f36bba added test boilerplate and helpers
* 3441a8e Update README.md
* 92d5200 absolute script and css paths
* 81cee14 move history fallback to webpack server config
* 2cd850b using history fallback
* 31208bf Update README.md
* c5ad6ad Update README.md
* 0c7231d Update README.md
* 6aedde6 fix npm start on windows machines
* ec41961 Create README.md
* 7afaf3a added google maps by default
* 0736160 add lodash
* f6a7716 use store with middleware
* 14813f8 middleware setup included by default
*   1b82228 (tag: 1.0.0) Merge branch 'master' of github.com:StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter
|\  
| * fe018bf add default reducer
* | 3aa34af added css
|/  
* e4c4496 state-1 -> stage-1
* 4709b14 added babel preset
* 05173d9 used class container as root node
* 148f186 added bootstrap
* 9128a89 code cleanup
* dd358d4 reorder imports
* 3f0e441 update default text
* 9eff420 action and reducer setup
* 246b131 added redux
* f71dda3 add react redux and redux
* 544ddfd update repository field
* dedb285 update package.json
* dff784d initial commit
```

output from `git branch --all`

```
  HEAD
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

I was able to commit after running `git branch -D HEAD`

The outputs now look like:

`git status`

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

`git log --all --oneline --decorate --graph`

```
* 8a21399 (HEAD -> master) First working version (from git-gui)
* 2b459d6 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Create .babelrc
*   a7b92d5 Merge branch 'master' of github.com:StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter
|\  
| *   29ebda4 Merge pull request #8 from megadix/master
| |\  
| | * 7a74747 Filter out IntelliJ IDEA project files in .gitignore
| * |   decca90 Merge pull request #10 from dkarter/master
| |\ \  
| | * | 94692d5 Use destructuring to import Component
| | |/  
| * |   ff4d48c Merge pull request #24 from tsurupin/add-global-navigator
| |\ \  
| | * | d976e01 Add global navigator setting to modify the error, 'navigator is not defined', in testing with react-router link
| * | |   b198de2 Merge pull request #29 from hex13/master
| |\ \ \  
| | |/ /  
| |/| |   
| | * | 6246c47 fix typo in README.md
| |/ /  
* | | c62b60e moved babel config to webpack
|/ /  
* | 2eba18e (tag: 1.1.0) added reactrouter
* | 3ea279e Update package.json
* | 78c0fed tweak mocha test command for windows users
|/  
* 3f36bba added test boilerplate and helpers
* 3441a8e Update README.md
* 92d5200 absolute script and css paths
* 81cee14 move history fallback to webpack server config
* 2cd850b using history fallback
* 31208bf Update README.md
* c5ad6ad Update README.md
* 0c7231d Update README.md
* 6aedde6 fix npm start on windows machines
* ec41961 Create README.md
* 7afaf3a added google maps by default
* 0736160 add lodash
* f6a7716 use store with middleware
* 14813f8 middleware setup included by default
*   1b82228 (tag: 1.0.0) Merge branch 'master' of github.com:StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter
|\  
| * fe018bf add default reducer
* | 3aa34af added css
|/  
* e4c4496 state-1 -> stage-1
* 4709b14 added babel preset
* 05173d9 used class container as root node
* 148f186 added bootstrap
* 9128a89 code cleanup
* dd358d4 reorder imports
* 3f0e441 update default text
* 9eff420 action and reducer setup
* 246b131 added redux
* f71dda3 add react redux and redux
* 544ddfd update repository field
* dedb285 update package.json
* dff784d initial commit
```

`git branch --all`

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

git version 2.7.4 and I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: What is the output of `git status` and `git log --all --oneline --decorate --graph`?

Comment: Your choice of platform, git version and underlying file system may be relevant.

Comment: What is the output of `git branch --all`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the repository has a branch called `HEAD`. Since HEAD keeps track of the current working commit, Git becomes confused between the branch named HEAD and git's internal pointer to the current working commit (hence `warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous` messages.)

You could try `git branch -D HEAD` (the normal way to remove a branch), but I am not sure whether or not this would confuse git even more.